# Puppeteer log inside page.evaluate

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

How can I console.log something inside the page.evaluate, passing it to node and using it **during** the evaluation of the page?

I actually want to log the progress of the page.evaluate to the console and show some results to the user.

Comment: When you say "the user", do you mean the Puppeteer/Node context or the browser context? If you mean Puppeteer/Node, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58089425/how-do-print-the-console-output-of-the-page-in-puppeter-as-it-would-appear-in-th) for printing objects to the console.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Update for puppeteer 12, adapted from [the current documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v12.0.1/docs/api.md#event-console):

```
page.on('console', async (msg) => {
  const msgArgs = msg.args();
  for (let i = 0; i < msgArgs.length; ++i) {
    console.log(await msgArgs[i].jsonValue());
  }
});

await page.evaluate(() => console.log('hello', 5));
await page.evaluate(() => console.log({ foo: 'bar' }));
await page.evaluate(() => console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Shows the following results:

```
hello  
5  
{ foo: 'bar' }  
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Comment: I would suggest using consoleObj.text() rather than _text as _text indicates usage of a private variable

Comment: @Colin Hi do you know if theres other properties besides .text()? What if I Want to get an arraybuffer that was printed to the console?

Comment: Even if I don't log anything this message *"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"* appears in my console

Comment: This does not print arrays, just gives JSHandle@array

Comment: @tim-montague Updated for latest pptr

Answer (score 18):

The easiest way to get it to work exactly like you'd expect

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.on('console', (log) => console[log._type](log._text));
```

Answer (score 10):

A lot of the answers provided previously no longer work today. Also one thing that can be very annoying on some pages, is the "warning" messages which pollutes the output. One way to fix that is to filter for the type of the message. The following code helps reduce the noise and works with current versions of Puppeteer:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.on('console', consoleMessageObject => function (consoleMessageObject) {
    if (consoleMessageObject._type !== 'warning') {
        console.debug(consoleMessageObject._text)
    }
});

await page.goto('https://google.com');
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    console.log('Browser scope.');
    return 'Normal scope.';
});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 5):

**Update for version 1.15.x and above - Jan 2020**

In the latest version args has been replaced with _args.

So when you are using `page.evaluate()` or `page.evaluateHandle()` and you want to get the `console.log()` text from the browser context back to node, use the following code and make sure to set the listener before any `console.log()` calls:

**Code:**

```
    // First we register our listener.
    page.on('console', msg => {
    for (let i = 0; i < msg._args.length; ++i)
        console.log(`${i}: ${msg._args[i]}`);
    });

    // Then we call the log.
    page.evaluate(() => console.log('Hello World'));
```

**Explanation:**

You can't see the `console.log()` text in your node console or set node breakpoints inside `page.evaluate()` or `page.evaluateHandle()`, because the code inside those functions is running only in the browser context. If you would launch puppeteer in none headless mode you would see the `console.log()` message showing in the browser.

**Sidenote:**

In most cases you don't really need to log inside the browser context and you can do the same work in the 'Console' tab of your browser 'Developer tools' section.

Answer (score 4):

I like @[Vaviloff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245945/3931488)'s answer, but you will log the whole ConsoleMessage object when you may just want the text. Thus, I personally use the below:

```
const EOL = require('os').EOL;
const _page = await browser.newPage();

_page.on('console', _fCleanLog);

function _fCleanLog(ConsoleMessage) {
    console.log(ConsoleMessage.text + EOL);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I am trying to share my workaround if it helps anybody in future.

1. Print all the console outputs to stdout including warning, error, log:

   ```
   page = await browser.newPage();
   page.on("console", (consoleObj) => console.log(consoleObj.text()));
   ```
2. Print everything except warning:

   ```
   page.on('console', consoleObj => {
       if (consoleObj.type() !== 'warning') {
           console.log(consoleObj.text());
       }
   })
   ```
3. Print only logs (Ex: `console.logs`).

   ```
   page.on('console', consoleObj => {
       if (consoleObj.type() === 'log') {
           console.log(consoleObj.text());
       }
   })
   ```

The last one helped me more to debug efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

Implement the `notifyUi` function in this code sample:

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.on('console', (...args) => {
    this.notifyUi('[chrome] ' + args[0]);
});
await page.goto(url);
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    console.log('I am alive');
    return Promise.resolve(true);
});
this.notifyUi('Evaluation returned with ' + result);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.on("console", msg => {
for (let i = 0; i < msg.args().length; ++i)
console.log(`${i}: ${msg.args()[i]}`);
});
```

try this one if none of the above works. shows no error logs but only the log I created.

Answer (score 2):

I share [this solution](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/3051#issuecomment-411647065) for future readers who would more like to know how to get the returned value of an evaluation instead.

```
const element = await page.$("a selector");
const text = await page.evaluate(element => element.textContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
await page.evaluate(()=>{
      var string = 'I want to print this';
      return string;
}).then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 1):

This one isn't featured yet:

```js
// expose the function "logInNodeJs" for use from inside page context 
await page.exposeFunction('logInNodeJs', (value) => console.log(value));

// Now you can call logInNodeJs(value) from inside page context like below
await page.$eval('selector', (el) => {
    logInNodeJs('some test value'); // calls the exposed function from page context
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Today in 2021 with puppeteer 8.x.x the main answer not show us the full description of the console object. For example, you can't get all the error stack trace text, message.text() contain just a few information about the js errors.

My best way to do this in another comment here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66801550/9026103

Answer (score 0):

Update for puppeteer 12, adapted from [the current documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v12.0.1/docs/api.md#event-console):

**Work on Playwright the last version too.
In the previous version of this answer, if the number is dynamic "hello" is logged without the number "5". The number logs some rows below.**

Example:

```
firstHello
secondHello
thirdHello
...
1
2
3
```

```
page.on('console', async (msg) => {
        const msgArgs = msg.args();
        const logValues = await Promise.all(msgArgs.map(async arg => await arg.jsonValue()));
        console.log(...logValues);
    });

await page.evaluate(() => console.log('hello', 5));
await page.evaluate(() => console.log({ foo: 'bar' }));
await page.evaluate(() => console.log([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Shows the following results:

```
hello 5  
{ foo: 'bar' }  
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.on('console', ConsoleMessage => console.log(ConsoleMessage.text));
```