# page.evaluate not returning response when scraping with Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

- Puppeteer version: 9.0.0
- Platform / OS version: google cloud functions
- Node.js version: 14

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

exports.MyFunc = function MyFunc(req, res) {

  MyFunc(req, res);
  async function MyFunc(req, res) {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await getSearchResults();
    
     async function getSearchResults() {

      const url = `https://abc.redacted.com/search?q=${query}&f=&orderBy=${sort_by}&skip=0&take=10`;
      console.log(url);
      await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "domcontentloaded" });
      console.log("Page downloaded"); // It console logs till here

      const getResults =  await page.evaluate(() => {
      let items = [];
      const results = document.querySelectorAll(
        "#mainArea > router-view > ma-serp > div > div.results > div > compose > div > div.results > ma-card"
      );
      console.log(results);

      for (let result of results) {

        console.log(result.querySelector("span")?.innerText ?? "");

        items.push({ title: result.querySelector("span")?.innerText ?? "", })
      };
      return items;
      });

      const data = getResults;
      res.status(200).json(data);  // just getting {}

      await browser.close();
      }
  }
}
```

IDK why but `page.evaluate()` doesn't console log anything and doesn't return anything to node environment. From three days I'm trying different solutions on stack overflow and GitHub issues but no success until now.

- I've also tried `promise.resolve()` when returning from `page.evaluate` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: It looks like you have an HTTP function and if so, you need to make sure it follows the [Express notation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events). Also, you can't create a function inside a function, they have to be created separately. After fixing this, this function may work.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `page.evaluate()` you are actually operating within the browser context, not Node. So `console.log` outputs to the browser context and you will not see anything in your Node console.

Here is a workaround to get the browser context to output to the node console:

```
const page = await browser.newPage();

page.on('console', consoleObj => console.log(consoleObj.text()));
```

Reference: [Puppeteer log inside page.evaluate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46198527/puppeteer-log-inside-page-evaluate)